# Return an item by id

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I got this piece of code, I am learning from tutorial. I want to return an element by url which looks like `clients/1` instead of `clients?id=1`. How can I achieve this? Also, can the code below be made easier way?

```java
    @GetMapping
    public Client getClient(@RequestParam int id) {
        Optional<Client> first = clientList.stream().filter(element -> element.getId() == id).findFirst();
        return first.get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use [`@PathVariable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/clients")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Client getClient(@PathVariable int id) {
        return clientList.stream().filter(element -> element.getId() == id).findFirst().orElseThrow();
    }
```

Please note, the `Optional` can be unpacked with `orElseThrow` method. This will throw a `NoSuchElementException` in case there is no element found for the `id`.

Other solution would be to use `orElse(new Client(...))` to return a default value if nothing is found.

`get()` is not really recommended to be used. From the JavaDoc of the `get()` method:

> API Note:
> The preferred alternative to this method is `orElseThrow()`.

Even though `get()` may also throw a `NoSuchElementException`, similar to `orElseThrow`, usually the consensus is that `get` should not be used without `isPresent`, or should not be used at all. There several other methods to unpack the `Optional` without forcing you write an `if`.

The whole idea of the `Optional` is to overcome this by forcing you to think about the case when there is no value inside.